# Why isn't Javascript stack updating correctly in jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery code which allows users to "go back" through a table's pagination pages. The idea is that users can go to table page 1, then 6 then 5, and clicking the "back" button will direct them back to table page 6, then 1. I'm implementing this using a stack. Here is the code:

```
<script>

var currentPager = 'pager1';
var pagerStack = [];

$(function() {
//display tag
    $(".pagelinks a, .sortable a").each(function(index) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href', '#displayTable');
        var pagenum = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr('id', 'pager' + pagenum);

        $(this).click(function() {
            $("#reconForm").attr('action', href);
            $("#reconForm").submit();

            pagerStack.push(currentPager);
            currentPager = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(pagerStack.length);

            return false;
        });

    });
});

function pageBack() {
    alert(pagerStack.length);
    //Do pagerStack.pop() here eventually 
}
</script>
```

My console tells me that whenever a ".pagelinks a" is clicked, the currentPager is pushed, but the size is always one. When pageBack() is called, the alert tells me the size of pagerStack is 0. It seems that the array is being reinitialized every time a function begins/ends. Why is this and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this fiddle correct? http://jsfiddle.net/B4t38/

Comment: you click on links and submit a form...are you sure that you didn't leave the current page when you click on the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dr. Molle

The page with the script in it was, in fact, being reloaded on each ajax submit, as you suggested. I moved my javascript variable declrations into the parent jsp and now it seems to be working as expected. Thank you.